# SSL client certificate creation with HTML5 <keygen> tag

Tags: html, firefox, openssl

I've got some trouble with expiring client certificates on some project I'm working on, occuring in Firefox 21 and versions below.

The environment: There are client-pcs, which have one single client certificate for each of them. Those client certificates were installed by using the PKCS12 file format with export password set. The clients are calling a site with domain 'a.somedomain.net', every server request has 'b.somedomain.net' as target. The certificates are valid for '*.somedomain.net'. So far, so good, everything's fine.

Now they're expiring, so I wanted to have some update mechanism doing a quiet, no-user-action-required update of the certificates. I am checking the $_SERVER['SSL_CLIENT_V_REMAIN'] variable and performing an update if the number of remaining days is below a predefined value. That also works.

In case an update is required, I'm doing some http redirect to a script located at "b.somedomain.net". The form includes all DN data HTML5 browsers need for creating the public/private key pair and sending the public key to the form action url. That also works.

Now the server's signing the certificate via OpenSSL/PHP and returns the certificate with correct headers for recognization by the browser. But then FF tells me **"This personal certificate can't be installed because you do not own the corresponding private key which was created when the certificate was requested."**

The private key stays behind FFs doors, I only get the public key from FF, OpenSSL is fine with it and throws no errors. What am I doing wrong?

If there's more information needed, please comment.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

in the other Question Generating client side certificates in browser and signing on server">Generating client side certificates in browser and signing on server there is an Answer with an Link to [crosskeygen.js](https://github.com/harbulot/webidrepository/blob/master/core/src/main/resources/uk/ac/manchester/rcs/bruno/webidrepository/htdocs/crosskeygen.js) and the HTML Templates [HTML-Templates](https://github.com/harbulot/webidrepository/tree/master/core/src/main/resources/uk/ac/manchester/rcs/bruno/webidrepository/templates) that show how it works.
For me this was an great help.